# Cancelation token waits entire delay duration before cancelling

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0

In the following code, if the `UserCancelled` property is set to true, I want it to end the loop immediately and continue code.

The problem I'm facing is it continues after the 6 seconds passes, not before, which I thought the cancellation token would end the delay early.

What are the options to end this delay sooner?

```
CancellationTokenSource _source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = _source.Token;
foreach (var mock in lst)
{
    if (UserCancelled)
    {
       _source.Cancel();
       _source.Dispose();
       break;
    }
    
       label1.Text = mock.Name;
       await Task.Delay(6000, token);
                    
 }
    
 label1.Text += " Broke Out";
```

Comment: If it's in the Delay, its not in the code, thus you don't call the cancel. The Cancel should be called by the UserCanceled. Maybe use an event? Or don't use Task Delay and use a Timer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the cancellation is not requested until the continuation is executed after waiting for 6 seconds. Extract the cancellation source into a field and call `_source.Cancel()` at the moment you set `UserCancelled` to true.

`label1` gives me the hint this is some sort of UI code so I would refactor it something like this:

```cs
// this is a field
private CancellationTokenSource _source = new CancellationTokenSource();

// call this from whatever handler/command and pass _source.Token to it:
private async Task DoMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var mock in lst)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
    
       label1.Text = mock.Name;
       await Task.Delay(6000, token);                    
     }
    
     label1.Text += " Broke Out";
}

// can be a simple event handler, too (eg. for some btnCancel.Click)
private void OnCancelCommand()
{
    // avoid double cancellation and ObjectDisposedException
    if (UserCancelled)
        return;
    _source.Cancel();
    _source.Dispose();
    UserCancelled = true;
}
```

Comment: excellent answer and because mine was a UI, I had to wrap the await Tak.Delay in a try catch block with `catch(TaskCanceledException)` and all the code is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

If `UserCancelled` is already set to `true` when we enter the loop, then you should cancel immediately.

If `UserCancelled` was `false` on initial check then you go to the `Task.Delay` and start waiting. No any additional checks are performed during the wait.

After 60s the work resumes and you go on then next iteration of the loop. And here, again, if f `UserCancelled` is set to `true`, you will cancel and exit, else will wait for another 60s.

The best solution here will be to make the `_source` variable available to the code, which is setting `UserCancelled`. And such a code will call `_source.Cancel()` directly.